# Sci-fi short story about a person that has to run across country and ages drastically as he's exposed to the elements

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a sci-fi short story many years ago but can't recall the title.

It is about a person that has to run across country to get to a place of sanctuary within a period of time, somewhere about 10 minutes.  He is aging drastically as he is exposed to the elements.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, can you tell us anything more about the world this story is set in?

Answer (score 21):

This is probably "Frost and Fire" by Ray Bradbury. It first appeared in [Planet Stories, Fall 1946](https://archive.org/details/Planet_Stories_v03n04_1946-Fall/page/n95/mode/2up) (with a different title). A spaceship lands on a planet whose sun's radiation vastly accelerates the crew's metabolism. The survivors very quickly forget their origin. Babies grow like crazy, and a whole lifespan lasts about eight days.

A man sees the spaceship, is curious about it, and persuades several others to try to get to it during a nighttime. If this is right, that is probably the part you remember.

Comment: And if this is correct, that's a duplicate.

Comment: Yup, this was my immediate thought as well.